Book about humans on alien planet that has a regular mass extinction event
Do you know the name of a book about humans using technology to adapt to a planet where most life is regularly killed off?
The species on this planet behave like insects. They mate like cicadas such that they lay a bunch of eggs and a cataclysm kills off the adults. This cataclysm is like clock-work; it's some celestial event that burns the planet.
Humans use incubators and must mate like cicadas in order to continue the species on this new planet.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Was it a hardcover, paperback or e-book?  Do you remember the cover art?  Were the humans trapped there, they couldn't evacuate somewhere more hospitable?

There was a Larry Niven story called "Flare Time", which I am now learning is part of a larger collection of stories by various authors, under the editorship of Harlan Ellison, called Medea: Harlan's World.  In it, the world of Medea is periodically thrown into an environmental cataclysm by solar flares, to which the native species of "centauroids" and the visiting humans must adapt to survive.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medea:_Harlan%27s_World

This could be Cycle Of Fire by Hal Clement.
There's not a lot to go on, but the planet regularly flips between two different dominant species when the environmental conditions change drastically but

 it's the same species who mostly die out and their juvenile version. I don't remember if they remain as literal eggs or not.

The story itself is about humans who have crashed there and are trying to survive while working out what's actually going on.
https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?3330

No human mating like cicadas in that book.
